# Add count whenever any entity is fetched Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My model looks like

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='articles'
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Article Title'
    )

    count = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Frequency Count'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and my urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('article', ArticleViewSet, basename='article')

urlpatterns = [
    path('viewset/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now I wan't to add functionality such that whenever any article is fetched i.e

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewset/article/{pk}
```

than 'count' of article of `id=pk` becomes `count = count+1`

so that I can sort them according to this count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by sending a request like `fetch=true` or `seen=true` from client side whenever the api been fetched by the client i.e the client will sent you 
`fetch=true` whenever fetch the api and from backend you have to catch that flag and have to check if `fetch=true` and increase `instance.count += 1` and save the change in your model.

**CODE**: First change your model by providing `count` field a default value, this time its 0.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='articles'
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Article Title'
    )

    count = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Frequency Count',
        default=0
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and then do migration.

and then `VIEW`

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        fetch = request.GET.get('fetch', False)
        article = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        if fetch:
            article.count += 1
            article.save()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and then request with `article/1/?fetch=true`

**you can also do it without `fetch` flag** too,

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        article = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        article.count += 1
        article.save()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

now reqeust with `article/1/`

Comment: I am also applying some search function on ```articles``` which returns ```list``` of ```articles```,Is there a way to increase ```count``` of top 3 objects of that list.

Comment: post a question regarding this and then share the link here, i will try to give answer.

Comment: here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058526/increasing-the-count-field-of-model-whenever-a-search-is-applied

Answer (score 1):

I figured out from [@Tanvir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61850526/12965178)'s answer

When we retrieve object we can update the count there itself i.e

```
    def retrieve(self, request):
         obj = self.get_object()
         obj.count = obj.count+1
         obj.save()
         serializer = self.get_serializer(obj)
         return Response(serializer.data)
```