# Increasing the count field of model whenever a search is applied

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a search api

```
   class SearchViewSet(RetrieveModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        query = self.request.query_params.get("query")

        final_queryset = search(query,queryset,#some logic)

        #logic to generate serialiser and return serialiser.data
        serialiser = self.get_serializer(final_ueryset, many=True)
```

`search` function returns a list of articles i.e

```
   type(final_queryset) is List
```

And. I wan't to return the articles order_by('count) as well.
Now I wan't to increase the `count` of top 3 articles from the final_queryset is there a way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way for doing this
Just simply iterate on the list and increment the `count` of the objects in the list

```
   class SearchViewSet(RetrieveModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        query = self.request.query_params.get("query")

        final_queryset = search(query,queryset,#some logic)

        # to increment the count of top 3 entity_aliases
        for instance in final_queryset[:3]:
            instance.count += 1
            instance.save()

        #logic to generate serialiser and return serialiser.data
        serialiser = self.get_serializer(final_ueryset, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `created_at` field in your model, then use this field to find top 3 item or latest 3 items like this, and then increase count

```
    queryset = Article.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:3] # it will return a queryset of latest 3 items
    for article in queryset:
        article.count += 1
        article.save()
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(article)
```

Note: I only shared the logic part here, and i can't test it in my local, but it should work and help you to  get the idea. Use it on your need.

Comment: ```final_queryset``` is a ```list``` and thus order_by will not not work on a ```list```

Comment: Can you share the list items ?

Comment: I have updated the question and I wan't to add order_by('count') functionality in search results as well I have mentioned this in question as well